# Unable to start my apache

Tags: server, apache2, php

After I downgraded my php5.5 to php5.3.10, I no longer able to start my apache2.

Here is what I get:

```
sudo service apache2 start 
[sudo] password for fcasili:   
* Starting web server apache2                                                
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/access_compat.load: No such file or directory Action 'start' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I already tried purging my apache2 and re-install it again. Please help

Comment: When you purged apache2, did you erase the configuration directory (`/etc/apache2`)? An old configuration file might be causing issues.

Comment: @Ross, no. do i have to delete all modules/files under /etc/apache2?

Comment: did you try enabling the access_compat module by adding an `Include` line to the apache2.conf file?

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and add the link in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a downgrade, I suppose by removing and re-installing packages.
This probably not removed all the configuration done previously.

The way the configuration of Apache is made in Ubuntu is no more to link every module load and configuration file separately and explicitely in the main config file but just by pointing to the site-enabled/, mods-enabled/ and conf-enabled/ directories for files ending by .conf and .load.
The content of these directories is in turn symbolic links towards a file in the site-available/, mods-available/ and conf-available/ directories, where the packages provided files are stored.

I suspect that the downgrade you've done removed the access_compat.load file in the mods-available/ directory but left the symbolic link mods-enable/access_compat.load untouched, so making it a dead link.
Look in your mods-enable/ directory for dead links and remove it (or them).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is in  `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

So all you have to do is disable the line that makes the problem:

1. Open the file:

   gksu gedit  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
2. Find the line:

   Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

   type `access_compat.load`
3. Comment it as follows:

   `#Include mods-enabled/access_compat.load`
4. save file and restart apache

   `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score -3):

apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: Where is the explanation?

Comment: Like Rolandi said, how do you think this will solve the issue? Also, **Note to Reviewers:** A technically incorrect answer is still an answer and shouldn't be deleted as VLQ.